# Will I have to repeat the training procedure if I close the Jupyter notebook after the model has finished training and I've saved it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, torch

The model has been trained, tested, and I have saved both the checkpoint and the model. After the training is complete, I load the stored model in the code. Do I need to retrain the model if I close the Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: No - if you saved the model properly you can just load it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is... no!
Actually saving a model (under format `.pt` basically) will store all the trained parameters under a pickle dictionary somewhere in persistent memory (CD or SSD). Closing a notebook only clean allocated memory (RAM or video RAM) but not persistent memory so you will lose an hypothetical variable `model` but not the saved parameters you trained. Note that the architecture is not store (only the weights and the name of the layers)